# how to reset the modal on react.js

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have some modal on my webpage. When user click the button modal opens. But there ara some input areas on the modal and i want clean them when user click the close section. Close section is not button it's a sign. When user open modal again he/she sees old input. It should't be that way. How can i fix this issue?

```
const AddCampaignModal = (props) => {

  return (
    <div>
       <Modal
          visible={props.visible}
          title="Add new campaign"
          onClose={props.onClose}
          size="medium"
        >
        <AddCampaignForm 
          i18n={props.i18n} 
          onClose={props.onClose}/>
        </Modal>
    </div>
  )
}

export default AddCampaignModal
```

Answer (score 0):

If the data from the inputs is in your component you can try something like this : In `closeModal` you can set the initial state of the component

```
const initialState = { name: null,//add your data// }

closeModal = () => {
        this.setState({ 
         ...initialState,
         modalIsOpen: false 
        });
    }
```

---

But if the state of the input comes from the Parent you need a new method to reset the data of the parent component that could be added as a callback in the same method.

```
    const initialState = {name: null,//add your data// }

closeModal = () => {
        this.setState({ 
         modalIsOpen: false 
        }, () => {
        this.props.resetInputData();
      });
    }
```